# Can I add fresh minced garlic to a jar of Huy Fong chili paste without risking botulism?

Tags: food-safety, chili-peppers, garlic, botulism

Can I add fresh minced garlic to a jar of Huy Fong chili paste without risking botulism?

Ingredients: Chili, salt, acetic acid, potassium sorbate and sodium bisulfite as preservatives, xanthan gum.

Comment: Are you asking if you can add it and leave it out without risk? Or keep it in the refrigerator?

Comment: I'm asking if i can keep it in the fridge without risk

Comment: I would probably not do it myself, as the garlic could "go bad", i.e. other bacteria could grow, even if there is no risk of botulism.

Comment: But garlic chili paste is a staple of Cantonese cuisine, so there should be a safe way to make it. Personally I would add the garlic every time I cook something.

Answer (score 1):

According to WHO
"botulinum will not grow in acidic conditions (pH less than 4.6), and therefore the toxin will not be formed in acidic foods (however, a low pH will not degrade any pre-formed toxin)."

Paste is probably acidic enough on it's own to kill any introduced botulinum from the garlic -reasonable quantity added-

To be extra sure, I would sprinkle mince garlic with a pinch of vit C or equivalent acid (and a pinch of salt to draw out flavor) before mixing.

Heat also sterlizes:
"Despite its extreme potency, botulinum toxin is easily destroyed. Heating to an internal temperature of 85°C for at least 5 minutes will decontaminate affected food or drink."